# multiple hibernate database connections fail

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I have a java web application that needs to control multiple MySQL databases (same schema) at the same time.

I’m using Tomcat as a web container and hibernate. Connecting up to 3 databases works fine for both reading and writing to the databases.

As soon as I attach the 4th database and write to this database the connection gets lost. I think that this is because of some limitation somewhere but I don’t have the slightest idea what and where.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Did you try to use the 4th DB as 3rd for a try? Did it works?

Comment: Thank you RC for taking time. Stupid but i restarted the server which had been running for weeks on end and that did the trick.